# optaplanner: modifying vehicle routing to let customers be not served

Tags: optaplanner

In a vehicle routing problem I want to eliminate the constraint that every customer must be served, but adding a prize for those who are served.

I'd like to add a virtual vehicle v_i for each customer c_i, such that v_i can serve only customer c_i, and when it happens it means that the customer is not served. Hence, when there are N customers, there are M real vehicles plus N virtual vehicles.

My doubt is: how can I set the valueRangeProviderRefs of the Customer class to avoid client c_j to be served by vehicle v_i, that is, can I make "vehicleRange" depend on a specific customer instead if refferring to a static List of vehicles?

Answer (score 0):

This is called **overconstrained planning**. Technically, `@PlanningVariable(nullable=true)` should allow this, but OptaPlanner 6.0 (and 6.1 currently too) does not support `nullable` for `chained` variables yet...

Workaround: Create 1 dummy `Vehicle`, which is ignored in all the score rules and add a score rule to reward any customer being serviced by a non-dummy Vehicle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I already tried with nullable=true and actually it would have been the best solution... (letting previousStand==null for not served customers).

I thought also to your workaround of creating a dummy vehicle v_d, but I thought that, even if I can write rules which don't consider customers served by v_d, the algorithm tries anyway to optimize the customer chain under v_d, that is wasting computational resource. Am I wrong?

Comment: In your pdf guide (page 70), I found this example

@ValueRangeProvider(id = "possibleRoomRange")
public List<Room> getPossibleRoomList() {
return getCourse().getTeacher().getPossibleRoomList();
}

and it seems that a planningVariable can be limited to a range depending on its planningEntity, right? If so this would prevent the optimizer to waste time by optimizing the unserved customers.

Comment: Optimizing the chain under v_d is indeed some wasting of computational resource, but I 'd still recommend that approach for now. To avoid that wasting, you can always add a filter on the move selector to ignore such moves... Feel free to create a jira that chained and nullable=true should also work together (this has some implications though).

Comment: As for a ValueRangeProvider on the entity for chained variables: that doesn't work well yet :( Avoid it. The chain correction is the problem there: given a chain of `A<-B<-C`, moving `B` to somewhere else implies creating `A<-C` which currently doesn't check if `A` is in `C`'s value range... Feel free to make a jira issue in our issue tracker about this too (there might be one already).

Comment: Also, in general, "ValueRangeProvider on the entity" shouldn't be used to force things like this. I even believe, if once it works well with chained variables, it still won't solve your problem. It seems like you're looking for "move filtering" (see docs).

Comment: Thank you again. And congratulations for optaplanner!