# Optaplanner: check if chained planning variable has anchor

Tags: optaplanner, chained, vehicle-routing

I'm modifying the vehicle routing Optaplanner example. Vehicles are replaced with individuals who have to travel around the city, but they can do so using different modes of transportation. So I have an attribute on the anchor (Vehicle in the example, Employee in my modified code) called `modeOfTransportation`.

When calculating the arrival time using the custom shadow variable listener from the example, I want to take the mode of transportation into account of course. But, when Optaplanner starts initialising my planning entities (consumers), it seems that they at first are not connected to an anchor. So I can't get my mode of transportation, and everything breaks down.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Below is what I want to accomplish.
`shadowVisit` is my planning entity, `shadowVisit.getEmployee()` should give me the anchor.
Doing a `shadowVisit.getEmployee()==null` check seems to hang the entire solving process.

```
arrivalTime = 
previousStopDepartureTime.plus(
shadowVisit.getLocation().getDistanceFrom(
shadowVisit.getPreviousStop().getLocation(), shadowVisit.getEmployee().getModeOfTransportation())
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I figured out what the issue was.
My problem is overconstrained, and I implemented a dummy employee as the solution (see [optaplanner: modifying vehicle routing to let customers be not served](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759314/optaplanner-modifying-vehicle-routing-to-let-customers-be-not-served))

I had not set a modeOfTransportation for my dummy, causing the null pointers. Sometimes is just good to write down a problem, makes you think hard enough to solve it!

Thank you very much for your input Geoffrey

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, because the chain principles guarantee that every chain has an anchor (see below).

Maybe your `@CustomShadowVariable`'s `sources` attribute doesn't include the anchor shadow var, and your custom variable listener is called before the anchor shadow variable listener is called.
OptaPlanner guarantees that it will call one type of variable listener for all domain classes before calling the next type. The order of those types of variable listeners is determined by that `sources` attribute (see second image).

[image]

[image]

Comment: agreed that it is strange. Of course in the beginning of the solving process, all planning entities are orphaned, but I'm sort of assuming that the chains are built from the anchors up, that the planning entities don't chain up together before being anchored.

Here are my variables in what is the Customer class in the TWVRP example

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "employeeRange", "visitRange" },
            graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
    private Stop previousStop; 

Employee is anchor.

Comment: @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeListener.class, sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "previousStop")})
    private LocalDateTime arrivalTime;

Comment: @AnchorShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "previousStop")
    private Employee employee;

Comment: OK, with a bit more debugging, I can see that when my variable listener is called, sometimes previousStop is set to an Employee and employee is null, and sometimes the other way around.